# How do I combine or merge 2 linked lists together to create a new list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to take two linked lists "list_1" and "list_2" and then combine them and put them into "list_3". I have the two lists created and just can't seem to figure out how to combine them. The code I've added is how I created my lists. Pretty new to pointers and linked lists so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class List
{
    public:
        node *head, *tail;
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add_node(int n)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            node *temp = new node;
            temp -> data = n;
            temp -> next = NULL;

            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
            else{
                tail -> next = temp;
                tail = tail -> next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to combine them ?  Add one at the end of the other ?  Or intermix the nodes ?  And what have you tried so far (not creating the list, but really attempt to merging them) ?

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)` is a *very*  convoluted way of doing something exactly once. Remove the loop.

Comment: Draw your input lists as boxes-and-arrows diagrams on paper. Then start at their heads and rearrange the arrows between the boxes the way you want them to be.  The end result is your output. Think for a while, perhaps have a cup of coffee, then translate your procedure into code.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)` ? what for?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "rewire" them. `head` of list B should be rewired to the `tail` of list A, so that you can delete the `List` object of list B, but its members would not be deleted. Introduce new method `merge(List* list)` parameter, and there rewire `this->tail` to `list->head`, and update `this->tail` to become `list->tail`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I combine or merge 2 linked lists together to create a new list

just use `add_node` iterating on the two lists to combine

here a proposal where *combine* modify the current list, it is easy to add a new constructor getting two list in arguments or a *static* method combine etc if you prefer these ways

I added some 'classic' methods to help and be able to use *valgrind* without having memory leaks, and also put *List* attributes *private* because to have them *public* is not a good way

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
  int data;
  node * next;

  node(int v) : data(v), next(nullptr) {}
};

class List
{
  private:
    node *head, *tail;

  public:
    List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    ~List() { clear(); }
    List & operator=(const List & l) {            
      clear();

      const node * n = l.head;

      while (n != nullptr) {
        add_node(n->data);
        n = n->next;
      }
      return *this;
    }
    // + copy constructor, move etc

    void clear() {
       while (head != nullptr) {
         tail = head->next;
         delete head;
         head = tail;
       }
       head = tail = nullptr;
    }

    void add_node(int n)
    {
      node * temp = new node(n);

      if(head == NULL)
      {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
      }
      else
      {
        tail -> next = temp;
        tail = tail -> next;
      }
    }

    void combine(const List & l1, const List & l2) {
      *this = l1;

      node * n = l2.head;

      while (n != nullptr) {
        add_node(n->data);
        n = n->next;
      }
    }

    void pr() const {
      const node * n = head;

      while (n != nullptr) {
        std::cout << n->data << ' ';
        n = n->next;
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  List l1, l2, l3;

  l1.add_node(1);
  l1.add_node(2);
  l1.add_node(3);

  l2.add_node(4);
  l2.add_node(5);

  l3.add_node(33);
  l3.pr();
  l3.combine(l1, l2);
  l3.pr();
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
/tmp % ./a.out
33 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==8413== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8413== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8413== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8413== Command: ./a.out
==8413== 
33 
1 2 3 4 5 
==8413== 
==8413== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8413==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8413==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 176 bytes allocated
==8413== 
==8413== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8413== 
==8413== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8413== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```